# Orchard CMS custom Blog Post

Tags: customization, orchardcms, blogs, orchardcms-1.8

I know that it is possible to customize the autoroute to generate the slug in a way customer likes.

Now I have customized my BlogPost content type to meet my client needs and all works fine.

After a while he wants to add another Blog to site with some different settings (eg: Autoroute needs different slug settings, a field I have added should not be there but he wants another one... etc)

So to make a long story short: I would need to use a different BlogPost content type for the second blog.

The site must be the same, I cannot split in two other sites.

Now the question:
"Is it possible in Orchard to define more than one blog and customize the BlogPost content type for each Blog in a different way?"

Thanks

Comment: BlogPosts are just Content Types. You can just create a new content type and add the parts/fields you need.

Comment: Yes but Blog adds more. I can create BologPost2 and customize it but my blog will keep using BlogPost

Comment: The List feature enables you to recreate a feature that should be very close to the native blog feature.

Comment: List seems a good advice. However I see that are deprecated and should not be used. http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Creating-lists